# Safari issues - parts of site broken/not reading css

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser

I'm having issues with my site in Safari. It looks fine in Chrome and Firefox, however it is fairly broken in Safari. It appears to have a problem reading the CSS - after using the Safari Develop tool on certain elements, it says there are no properties, even though when viewing the main css file within the Develop tool the properties are there.

I can't work out why this is happening only on certain elements and only in Safari.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Screenshots: Chrome vs Safari

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Screenshots would be very helpful. From what I can see the footer is not styled properly in Safari; CSS appears to validate (with the exception of some browser prefixes on keyframes).

Comment: Have added screenshots. As you said, the CSS is valid - if there was any errors in the CSS or linking of files then it wouldn't display correctly in Chrome and Firefox. Don't understand why it's having trouble in Safari

Comment: It's working for me.. OS ?

Comment: Hmm. Yeah macbook and ipad both displaying as shown in the screenshots above for me (the bad side). Ran a software update this morning too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Safari console was actually throwing a CSS error (although vague error).

You have a superfluous comma at the end of each of the keyframe animations in layout.css (around line 163). Unsure why the CSS validators didn't pick this up. The issue really didn't become a problem until you had nested curly braces in the media queries section. Somehow the error leached above the media queries to the footer and threw it off...

All others who may stumble upon this post...the moral is **do not place trailing semi-colons at the end of your keyframe declarations.**

WAS

```
@-moz-keyframes photoshop { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 80%; } ; }
@-moz-keyframes htmlcss { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 70%; } ; }
@-moz-keyframes premiere { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 65%; } ; }
@-moz-keyframes afx { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 55%; } ; }
@-moz-keyframes illustrator { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 55%; } ; }
@-moz-keyframes jquery { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 45%; } ; }
@-webkit-keyframes photoshop { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 80%; } ; }
@-webkit-keyframes htmlcss { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 70%; } ; }
@-webkit-keyframes premiere { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 65%; } ; }
@-webkit-keyframes afx { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 55%; } ; }
@-webkit-keyframes illustrator { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 55%; } ; }
@-webkit-keyframes jquery { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 45%; } ; }
```

FIXED

```
@-moz-keyframes photoshop { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 80%; } }
@-moz-keyframes htmlcss { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 70%; } }
@-moz-keyframes premiere { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 65%; } }
@-moz-keyframes afx { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 55%; } }
@-moz-keyframes illustrator { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 55%; } }
@-moz-keyframes jquery { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 45%; } }
@-webkit-keyframes photoshop { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 80%; } }
@-webkit-keyframes htmlcss { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 70%; } }
@-webkit-keyframes premiere { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 65%; } }
@-webkit-keyframes afx { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 55%; } }
@-webkit-keyframes illustrator { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 55%; } }
@-webkit-keyframes jquery { 0% { width: 0px; } 100% { width: 45%; } }
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, that was the issue for me too.